# Why is bootstrap data-target not needed?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've searched on the web and stackoverflow but didn't find the answer. So thought to ask here.

I think in Bootstrap, data-target is needed to associate the trigger element with the drop down. But why in some cases, the data-target is not needed? For example, the following works:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Item</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But how the program would know which dropdown to associate with when the link is clicked? Is it some sort of default behaviour that the enclosing element is the one to be associated with?

Answer (score 0):

The TOGGLE tells Bootstrap what to do and the TARGET tells Bootstrap which element is going to open.